# ListView don't grow in cross axis

Tags: flutter

A regular vertical ListView would fill all the space on both axes, and `shrinkWrap` would make it *shrink* on the main axis, however, how can I make it shrink on the cross axis, just taking as much space as its biggest child needs, while being constrained by the maximum available horizontal space? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do that, are you placing something next to it in a row?

Comment: @Tree The real case is an horizontal listview inside a vertical one, so naturally I need to keep it constrained in the cross axis (vertically) but without having to specify a height manually i.e. have it grow according to the biggest child.

Comment: Consider adding a fixed preferred size. While everything dynamic is cool ; it's not optimal for performances and maintainability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Children are laid out only when they are visible on screen. Which means `ListView` don't know the maximum cross-axis size of it's children.

If you have a small amount of children you can instead replace `ListView` by `SingleChildSrollView` and then add as a child a `Column` containing all your children

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 50.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          width: 100.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 50.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 50.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: How would you accomplish this if you need this behavior with PageScrollPhysics?